# Can not get this to work in Joomla 3.4+

Tags: mysql, joomla, distance, joomla3.0

Spent a few hours on this now and it just doesn't seem to work. A Listener hits my site and I grab their ip and ultimately there approximate latitude and longitude. I have a table of my Radio stations with their approximate latitudes and longitudes. I simply want to see if the new Listener is within 25 miles of one of my stations so I can give them that feed. If not, I will give them my global stream.

When I use the query below,

```
//Connect to database
// CONNECT TO JOOMLA DATABASE
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('cityName', 'countryCode', 'latitude', 'longitude')))
    ->select($db->quote('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') )
    * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )', 'distance'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__areas'))
    ->having($db->quote('distance') . ' < ' . $miles)
    ->order($db->quote('distance') . ' DESC')
    ->setLimit('1');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$row = $db->loadObject();

echo $distance = distance($latitude,$longitude,$row->latitude,$row->longitude,"M");
echo '<br />';
print_r($row);
    exit;
```

---

The output is:

stdClass Object ( [cityName] => Fort Lauderdale [countryCode] => US [latitude] => 26.122299 [longitude] => -80.143402 [( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.8898) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-114.031) ) + sin( radians(46.8898) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )] => ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(46.8898) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-114.031) ) + sin( radians(46.8898) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) )

Should not the result of the long calculation be a distance instead of a repeat of the calculation? I've tried about every combination I can think of except the right one. Could really use some help. Thanks!

Comment: so just comment your `print_r($row);`

Answer (score 0):

try just :

```
->select('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.